# regex to find everything enclosed between 00, and it may also include single 0 in between

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to find single line and multi line data enclosed between 00

Like

```
00some data 00
```

Or

```
00
This
Is multi line
Data00
```

Both can be selected

With regex like

```
/0{2}([^0]*)0{2}/gmi
```

However it fails if there is single 0 in between

Like

Like

```
00some 0data 00
```

Or

```
00
This
Is multi line
With 0 in between 
Data00
```

Comment: Get rid of the negative character class with 0 and just make it 0 or more tokens of any kind.

Comment: You need the `s` flag so that `.` will match newlines.

Comment: You should use: `00[^]*?00`

Comment: @anubhava Is `[^]` really valid? What are you inverting?

Comment: In Javascript `[^]` matches any character, including newline.

Comment: [working example](https://regex101.com/r/aCv9Q6/1)

Answer (score 2):

Converting my comment to answer so that solution is easy to find for future visitors.

You need to get rid of negated character class `[^0]` since your input may contain a `0` anywhere between pairs of `00` markers.

In Javascript you may use this simple regex:

```bash
00([^]*?)00
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aCv9Q6/1)

In Javascript a `[^]` matches any character, including newline.

Comment: If the string were `"00abc000"` this would capture `"abc"`. Prateek, do you want that or `"abc0"`? If the latter anubhava could easily modify his answer. Similar for `"000abc00"`. As an aside, I've not seen `[^]` before, though `[\s\S]` (or `[\d\D]`, etc.) is commonly used for that (when the DOTALL or single-line flag cannot be used). Interesting.